# Custom fonts are slowing my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uifont

How can make my app loads faster with custom fonts?

My simple iOS app needs 12 seconds to start. I used Xcode Instruments and I found that was because of the custom fonts that I used. If I run my app without this fonts - it loads in about 1,5 seconds. Custom fonts were used in TableView cell - two times in each. I had about 30 cell in this TableView.

I have only 3 fonts - 600 kb total.

Comment: I hope you have mention that font name in .plist file and write proper font name in your code.

Comment: Yes, I added fonts to .plist, i set font with IB. I have no problems with fonts on screen.

Comment: it's strange issue. Might be another reason!

Comment: You need to check the font names very carefully. There are no delays caused by slight misspellings of font file names; iOS searches the font catalog and eventually finds the right font but it takes some time.

Comment: And, you were testing on the real device, or ios simulator?

Comment: I tested on both of them - same result. If i make some changes in font names - i see no custom fonts in my app, that is why i think that i have no problems with font names.

Comment: Are they especially complex fonts? If you switch to basic sans-serf fonts, does it still take so much time to load? Some seemingly simple homemade fonts have lots of vector points that could slow down the draw rate.

Comment: No, it is Roboto font. Is it complex?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to install these fonts in your system and delete your fonts from your code. After that again add those fonts in your code and make sure fonts name and extension(.ttf) should be same on file folder and .plist file. 
I hope above process will work.